# RIA Services Filter descriptor

Tags: service, ria

I have a Filterdescriptor as shown below. The propertypath is of type 'char?'

```
<riaData:FilterDescriptor PropertyPath="Valid" Operator="StartsWith">
    <riaControls:ControlParameter PropertyName="Text" RefreshEventName="TextChanged"    ControlName="ValidFilterBox" />
</riaData:FilterDescriptor>
```

I get following InvalidOperationException when I filter by entering a value Y

> InnerException    {System.InvalidOperationException: A FilterDescriptor
>   with its PropertyPath equal to 'Valid' cannot be evaluated. --->
>   System.ArgumentException: Operator 'StartsWith' incompatible with
>   operand types 'Char?' and 'Char?' ---> System.ArgumentNullException:
>   Value cannot be null. Parameter name: method    at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.ValidateCallArgs(Expression
>   instance, MethodInfo method, ReadOnlyCollection`1& arguments)    at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance,
>   MethodInfo method, IEnumerable`1 arguments)    at
>   System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Call(Expression instance,
>   MethodInfo method, Expression[] arguments)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.LinqHelper.GenerateMethodCall(String
>   methodName, Expression left, Expression right)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.LinqHelper.GenerateStartsWith(Expression left,
>   Expression right)    at
>   System.Windows.Controls.LinqHelper.BuildFilterExpression(Expression
>   propertyExpression, FilterOperator filterOperator, Expression
>   valueExpression, Boolean isCaseSensitive, Expression&
>   filterExpression)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---}   System.Exception
>   {System.InvalidOperationException}

Comment: <riaData:FilterDescriptor PropertyPath="Valid" Operator="StartsWith">
                                            <riaControls:ControlParameter PropertyName="Text" RefreshEventName="TextChanged" ControlName="ValidFilterBox" />
                                        </riaData:FilterDescriptor>

Answer (score 0):

Sorting / Filtering / Grouping is really will be easy with using "RIA Services DataFilter Control for Silverlight".
http://riadatafilter.codeplex.com/